# Create new column with max value based on filtered rows with groupby in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a `spark` dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
foo = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,1,2,2,2], 'col': ['a','b','a','a','b'], 'value': [1,5,2,3,4],
'col_b': ['a','c','a','a','c']})
```

I want to create a new column with the `max` of the `value` column, groupped by `id`. But I want the `max` `value` only for the rows that `col==col_b`

My result spark dataframe should look like this

```
foo = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,1,2,2,2], 'col': ['a','b','a','a','b'], 'value': [1,5,2,3,4],
'max_value':[1,1,3,3,3], 'col_b': ['a','c','a','a','c']})
```

I have tried

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
w = Window.partitionBy('id')
foo = foo.withColumn('max_value', f.max('value').over(w))\
    .where(f.col('col') == f.col('col_b'))
```

But I end up losing some rows.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`when`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.when) function for conditionnal aggregation `max`:

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

w = Window.partitionBy('id')

foo = foo.withColumn('max_value', F.max(F.when(F.col('col') == F.col('col_b'), F.col('value'))).over(w))
```